# Laravel belongsToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Having a belongsToMany relation on the same model (Team Model) through custom pivot table (related_teams)

[image: related_teams table structure]

and my relation is like the following

[image]

now attaching and detaching  is working just fine , however as you see every team belongs to a city 
 .
so my question is how can i get a list of distinct cities from those attached teams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to achive but for example

```php
$this->attachedHotels->groupBy('city_id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby

or

```php
$this->attachedHotels->pluck('city_id')->unique();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-unique

Comment: yeah for sure pluck will do the trick and give me array of city ids , but what if in the same line i wanna return array of city objects ?

Comment: @EmadRashadMuhammed just ...unique()->map(function ($id) { return City::find($id); });